# Next-auth Github Provider Consume profile in Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next-auth

following the oficial documentation [next-auth Github Provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/github) I managed to implement SSO with the Next-auth Github provider for my App. The [Client API documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession) suggest to use **useSession()** to get the session, but is not returning the Github *username* (is what i need). So what I did is to override the profile response (see code snippet below). As you can see im logging the **profile** but just on the Terminal output.

So I would like to know how can i consume the **profile** data in the Frontend.

Thanks

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      async profile(profile: GithubProfile) {
        console.log('profile', profile)
        return {
          id: profile.id.toString(),
          name: profile.name,
          userName: profile.login,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.avatar_url,
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch profile data in client, you can do these ways:

1. Fetch data in SSR and send it to client
2. Make an API request in client and an API handler in `/api/` path to send response to request and also use `client_secret` just in backend and send the profile data to client.
3. (Recommended) -> Create an API handler and save the data in cookie with JWT method. This is secure and good for the server. Because you do not have to request every time to fetch. And your secret data will be secret :)